# Missing C & C++ compilers in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows, bash, cmake, windows-10, subsystem

I'm trying to compile LLVM using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (Windows 10 build 10.0.14342), but I keep getting cmake errors about how I'm missing C & C++ compilers. This is despite having gcc, g++, and build-essentials by using apt-get from within bash. My command is as follows:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86" ../llvm-3.8
```

I get a bunch of errors from CMake

```
CMake Error: Parse error in cache file /home/andrew-wsl/llvm/build/CMakeCache.txt. 
Offending entry: Debug Info builds.
CMake Error: Parse error in cache file /home/andrew-wsl/llvm/build/CMakeCache.txt. 
Offending entry: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:186 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:54 (project)


-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeDetermineCXXCompiler.cmake:185 (configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:54 (project)


-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:47 (try_compile):
  Unknown extension ".c" for file

    /home/andrew-wsl/llvm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c

  try_compile() works only for enabled languages.  Currently these are:

    ASM C CXX

  See project() command to enable other languages.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:54 (project)


-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
  The C compiler "/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:54 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/andrew-wsl/llvm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/andrew-wsl/llvm/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
andrew-wsl@COMPUTER:~/llvm/build$
```

CMakeError.log can be found here: http://pastebin.com/7rWYFGu5

CMakeOutput.log can be found here: http://pastebin.com/2BaEFTvR

I'm not sure what's going on as I was able to compile a helloworld program with gcc and g++ successfully.

Comment: Did you switch the compiler/toolchain within the same binary output directory? Looks like completely removing your binary output directory and try again from scratch would help. Cache errors are typical for the described scenario.

Comment: @Florian Is the folder you're talking about the one where the resulting Makefile will be outputted? If so then yes. I did completely remove it, but I still had the same CMake errors afterwards.

Comment: Very strange are the `(configure_file):
  configure_file Problem configuring file` errors. Looks like file access problems (out of disk space, permissions, etc.). Please also take a look into `CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log`.

Comment: @Florian I have attached a link to the CMakeError.log at the bottom of my question. It looks like some CMake test files were unable to be compiled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this is a known bug: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/272

Long story short, it's fixed as of build 14352.